# Дёргается камера, если зафиксировать тело в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема: Если зафиксировать тело, а в нём камера, то камера дёргается будто мало FPS, а как сделать по другому я ни знаю =(.

Код камеры:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Чувствительность")]
    private float mouseX;
    private float mouseY;
    public float mouseSensivX = 100;
    public float mouseSensivY = 50;

    [Header("Игрок и камера")]
    public Transform Player;

    private void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensivX * Time.deltaTime;
        mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensivY * Time.deltaTime;

        Player.Rotate(mouseX * new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
        transform.Rotate(-mouseY * new Vector3(1, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И камера и игрок выполняют все действия в методе *Update*. Определи, что должно двигаться первичней и на вторичном предмете измени метод *Update* на *LateUpdate*. Так, компилятор будет выполнять скрипты последовательно, а не одновременно.

Comment: Это было давно, но всё таки спасибо!